# npm/cucumber - '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, npm, cucumber

I have npm installed and shows version 9.2.0. When I run the command `npm run test`,  I get the error `'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command`. I have also checked if the environment variables are set as well. I cannot figure out why it happens.
Below is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "udemy_cucumber",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "practice bdd suite",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js --require cucumber.js --require step-definitions/**/*.js -f json:cucumber_report.json --publish-quiet"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@cucumber/cucumber": "^8.11.1",
    "@playwright/test": "^1.30.0",
    "chai": "^4.3.7",
    "cucumber-html-reporter": "^5.5.0",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "prettier": "^2.8.4"
  }
}
```

My folder structure is as below:
[image]

Can anyone help me out find what I missed, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out myself. Apparently, the windows terminal accepts backslashes to recognise the folder path. 
The command will be:

```
"test": ".\node_modules\.bin\cucumber-js --require cucumber.js --require step-definitions\**\*.js -f json:cucumber_report.json --publish-quiet"
```